# Line break inside a Barcode for excel

Tags: excel, barcode

wanting to add a line break inside a Barcode using free 3 of 9 Barcode font. So if I scan *Text1&Text2* in notepad it comes out as

Text1
Text2
I'm unable to find a simple way of doing this.

Comment: Is there any free barcode fonts that would work?

Answer (score 0):

3of9 is restricted to 43 signs, CR/FL is not part of this 43 characters, so you cant use `carriage return` or `line feed` in this code. The only way to get this into this code is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_39#Full_ASCII_Code_39). But this means you cant scan and insert the code into the cell, you need to scan, maintain (replace special sign by CR/LF) and then insert this modyfied text into the cell.

You can try [code128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128), this should fit your requirement.